# fwrite in php not working in binary mode

Tags: php

I am a .net guy and have got a code which works on one of our servers but not on the other, not even on my local machine. The code snippet is given below:

```
//$flocal1 = fopen($MVfile_name.".txt", "w");
//@fwrite($flocal1, "my name is gaurav pandey!!!");
//opening file
$flocal = fopen($MVfile_name, $mode);
```

//writing to file

```
if (!(@fwrite($flocal, $contents))) 
{
```

//writing error if writing operation failed

```
  exit(NotUpload);

}
```

//closing file 
     fclose($flocal);

As we can see, I tried same code with writing a text file with a string and that worked fine, but with binary files, I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Windows server, use the *b* flag to fopen.

```
fopen($filename, 'wb');
```

This should already by set by PHP according to the manual, but maybe you are on an old server where this isn't the case.

Comment: But then how this code is working fine on some other machines? I am not able to understand.

Comment: You question does not contain enough info to help here. Which charset is the file saved as? How do you know $flocal is the correct value? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I am using a webcam recorder and it posts the value to my php file, the file stream is of type .mp4. $flocal might be the correct value as the file is created first time here and the file stream is being written into it.